# pybot not making test suite when there is a single case

Tags: python, testing, robotframework

I run pybot using this command,

```
pybot --argumentfile a
```

File 'a' has the list of robot test cases and variable arguments as,

```
-v test_type:SUITE
/home/sk/a.robot
/home/sk/b.robot
```

Now, the test cases are run with ids, s1-s1-t1 and s1-s2-t2. Output.xml contains,

```
<suite id="s1" name="A & B">
<suite source="/home/sk/a.robot" id="s1-s1" name="A">
<test id="s1-s1-t1" name="Log Test">...</test>
```

Now, i removed one case and file 'a' has only one case as,

```
-v test_type:SUITE
/home/sk/a.robot
```

Output.xml contains,

```
<suite source="/home/sk/a.robot" id="s1" name="A">
<test id="s1-t1" name="Log Test">
      -----------------</test></suite>
```

Robot doesn't create the sub-suites s1 under parent suite s1 any more and instead it runs the testcase with ids s1-t1. This inconsistent way of creating test suites is making DOM parsing of output.xml difficult for me.

Is there a way to force robot to always create a test suite if it is run with `--argumentfile` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get robot to automatically add this special top-level suite when you run only a single suite. Only when you run two or more suites will Robot automatically generate this top level suite.

This feature is mentioned in the robot framework user's guide, in a section titled [Specifying test data to be executed](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#specifying-test-data-to-be-executed):

> It is also possible to give paths to several test case files or
>   directories at once, separated with spaces. In this case, Robot
>   Framework creates the top-level test suite automatically, and the
>   specified files and directories become its child test suites.

**Note**: this has absolutely nothing to do with the use of argument files. You'll get exactly the same results if you put the arguments directly on the command line.

### Rethinking how you run suites

One solution is to start your test run one folder up: put all of your suites inside a single folder, and always run just that single folder. This will always give you a consistent top-most suite. You can still specify individual suites, but by suite name rather than file name

For example, instead of this:

```
-v test_type:SUITE
/home/sk/a.robot
```

You would do this:

```
-v test_type:SUITE
--suite a
/home/sk
```

This has an added benefit that you can create a top-level suite initialization file (eg: `/home/sk/__init__.robot`) that will always get applied. See [Initialization files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#initialization-files) in the robot framework user's guide.

**Note:** If you have other things in `/home/sk` besides test suites, you might want to move all of your tests to a sub-folder (eg: `/home/sk/tests/a.robot`, `/home/sk/tests/b.robot`, etc)